# Why is the MuiThemeProvider overriding a component style?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have an outer component that uses MuiThemeProvider:

```
<MuiThemeProvider theme={full_theme_e}>
    <div>
    <AppBar />
    <Filter />
    </div>
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

In my filter component I define a custom style:

```
const styles = {
  expansionPanel: {
    borderTopLeftRadius: 0,
    borderTopRightRadius: 0,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
    borderBottomRightRadius: 0,
  }
};
```

Apply to the component:

```
<ExpansionPanel className={classNames(classes.expansionPanel, className)}
```

And use the style in my export:

```
export default withStyles(styles)(Filter);
```

The problem is my custom style gets overwritten by the MuiThemeProvider, why?
[image: Chrome showing style being overwritten]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const styles = {
  expansionPanel: {
    '&:first-child': {
      borderTopLeftRadius: 0,
      borderTopRightRadius: 0,
      borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
      borderBottomRightRadius: 0,
    }
  }
};
```

Same for `:last-child`, `:nth-child`...

Syntax for css colon selectors:

```
'&:[selector]': {
  ...
}
```